# How to parse a list of Json objects in Haskell?

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I have a data class:

```
data MyData = MyData { a :: Int, b :: String }
instance ToJSON MyData where
  ....

instance FromJSON MyData where
  ....
```

I can parse a single object from json:

```
get :: IO (Maybe MyData)
get = do
  res <- getSingleItemHttp
  return $ decode $ responseBody res
```

How can I get a list of MyData?

```
get2 :: IO [MyData]
get2 = do
      res <- getManyItemsHttp

      --????
      return $ decode $ responseBody res -- doesn't compile
```

How would I go about parsing responseBody to `List`?

Comment: please add the error message to your question - because in this case the error message would have told you exactly wher ethe problem was - the missing `Maybe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work as it is once you pass in an array (and decode as a list) so you probably just have to change your signature to `get2 :: IO (Maybe [MyData])`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, OverloadedStrings #-}
module Json where

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Text
import Data.ByteString.Lazy

data MyData = MyData { a :: Int, b :: String }
  deriving (Generic, Show)

instance FromJSON MyData

example :: ByteString
example = "[{ \"a\": 1, \"b\": \"Hello\" }, { \"a\": 2, \"b\": \"World\" }]"
```

### example

```
λ> decode example :: Maybe [MyData]
Just [MyData {a = 1, b = "Hello"},MyData {a = 2, b = "World"}]
```

---

### your problem

would be something like this: if you try

```
get :: [MyData]
get = decode example
```

the compiler will complain with

> Couldn't match expected type `[MyData]` with actual type `Maybe a0` …

which should give you a big hint.

You can still get your signature with [`Data.Maybe.maybeToList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:maybeToList):

```
get :: [MyData]
get = Prelude.concat . maybeToList $ decode example
```